# running count within group -SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to get a running count of items within a group as below, however I'm getting some unexpected results, Do I want to be using something else such as RowNumber?

=RunningValue(Fields!SKU.Value, Count, "GROUP1")

Or would I be better off doing this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon how you are grouping or if you have any visibility settings, so that it sometimes will give you strange results.  To get more accurate results if you have a strange grouping or visibility setting, it may be easier to do it in SQL.

Without more information on the table you are calculating running value on, I cannot be of more help.

If you can give us a sample of what your data is looking like and how the running value is looking it may be of more help as well.